# R shiny: selectInput items always scroll on top of a fixedPanel

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have an R shiny file that includes a banner at the top of the page via fixedPanel().  It also has a sidebar with a menu created with selectInput().  When I scroll the page up, the selectInput menu is the only UI item that scrolls on TOP of the banner.  I've tried putting the sidebar and selectInput items in an absolutePanel prior to including the fixedpanel, thinking that this might cause them to be in a lower "layer", but this did not prevent the behavior.  Below is code to produce this behavior.  Note that I've added a blank image with 1600 pixels just so that there is something to scroll, and I've not included any other UI items (but they would scroll BELOW the fixedPanel).  Here's the app.R file:

```
library(shiny) 

shinyApp(
   ui <- shinyUI(
      fluidPage( 

         absolutePanel(0, 0, width="100%", height="100%",

            # Leave a gap for the fixed panel containing the RAFT banner at the top of the page.
            fluidRow(
               img(src="", height=110)
            ),

            fluidRow(
               sidebarPanel(

                  # Insert a menu.
                  selectInput(
                     inputId="select", 
                     label="Select:",
                     choices=1:4
                  ),
                  img(src="", height=1600)
               )
            )
         ),

         # Insert a fixed panel containing the banner at the top of the page.
         fixedPanel(top="0%", height="60", left="0%", width="100%",
            img(src="banner.jpg", height=90, width=600)
         )
      )
   ),

   server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
   })
)
```

And here is the "banner.jpg" image that is referenced:

[image: banner.jpg]

Is this expected behavior?  Is there a way to get selectInput menu items to stay BELOW the fixedPanel when the page is scrolled up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After not getting any responses, I began digging through the CSS and JS files that support the shiny package.  I converted the shiny R code to HTML and began a trial and error process of first deleting files, and then deleting lines in a file, and I discovered that in file *selectize-bootstrap3.css* the class selector `.selectize-input` is defined to have a `z-index` of 1.  This is apparently high enough to make it float above the fixedPanel element that I created to use as a banner.  The solution was to give the fixedPanel a higher z-index, so I replaced this code:

```
     fixedPanel(top="0%", height="60", left="0%", width="100%",
        img(src="banner.jpg", height=90, width=600)
     )
```

with this code:

```
     fixedPanel(style="z-index:100;",
        top="0%", height="60", left="0%", width="100%",
        img(src="banner.jpg", height=90, width=600)
     )
```

This solved the problem.